# Headless Google Chrome Proxy Server Settings

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, proxy

I'm using Selenium webdriver with Google Chrome. This is the code I was using to set the proxy for chrome:

```
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % my_proxy)
```

This code worked for months. I'm coming back now and it is not working... I've tried older versions of Selenium, Chrome, Chromium, and the webdriver. None of the changes I do seem to work :(

Additionally, running chrome.exe from the command line while passing --proxy-server does **not** work! Chrome silently ignores the passed proxy...

Does anyone have any idea what is going on here? I've spent days trying to figure out how to get this simple selenium script working... Thanks so much :)

**EDIT:** I just tried running chrome.exe with the --proxy-server flags on a friend who has the same computer as mine and it worked...

Comment: You should specify your chrome and chromedriver versions.  Are you using Chrome v73?  And ChromeDriver 73.0.3683.68?

Comment: @orde tried launching chrome version 73.0.3683.103 (Official Build) (64-bit) and latest chromium build with --proxy-server flag and both of these silently ignore it...

Answer (score 0):

This was one of the chrome extensions I had installed... If `chrome.exe --proxy-server=xxx` is not working try removing all extensions.

Hopefully no one else has to waste 3 days on this :(